# WSL bash script are throwing error installing packages

Tags: bash, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run this sh script

```
sudo apt install git -y
```

with this command

```
sh file.sh
```

It throws

```
E: Command line option '
   ' [from -y
   ] is not understood in combination with the other options.
```

I'm in wsl

Comment: Run your script through fromdos. Or through `tr -d '\015'`. There's probably a stray DOS CR in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tr -d '\015' <file.sh >file-new.sh
```